# Recover from raid-5 to raid-6 reshape and crash, mdadm reports 0K/sec rebuild

Tags: mdadm, md

I have a question similar to [older thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/773244/mdadm-stuck-reshape-operation) but I'm not stuck with 100 % CPU usage.

I added one more disk (sdd1) to my 5x3TB raid-5 array and upgraded it to raid-6 which all went well until the power supply backplane failed and the server crashed mid-write.

mdadm --assemble required a temporary file, which I did specify at the upgrade and with --assemble --temporary-file=, it set the array as active and reshape. Problem is, it's reshaping at 0K/sec and won't finish.

The temporary file is zero byte by the way.

What are my options? I can access my files at the moment so if I can find 7 TB of storage, I can spend a few days to copy everything, fail and rebuild the array from scratch, but **is there a simpler option?**

**Can I fail sdd1 (the new drive I was trying to add) and restart a new five-disk raid-5 to six disk raid-6 array rebuild?** Or will that upset the assumed raid-6 array but mostly raid-5 in reality since it didn't finish the raid-5 -> raid-6 reshape?

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md127 : active raid6 sdd[0] sdb1[6] sdf[5] sde[3] sda[2] sdc[1]
      11721060352 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 18 [6/5] [UUUUU_]
      [=>...................]  reshape =  8.4% (247529472/2930265088) finish=3353419520.0min speed=0K/sec

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: Adding a disk to and reshaping a RAID without a backup is hardcore irresponsible.

Comment: @lain Thanks! :-) It's just my data so I'm the only one to suffer. I have a golden opportunity now to do a backup. 6 TB drives are around 250 € but that's one more odd sized drive to deal with.

Comment: SF is meant to be for Q&A about computer systems in a business environment.

Comment: @lain Well, EE is only meant for professionals too but we help the homebrew enthusiasts too. I don't see why not. Backup or not and professional or nor, the mdadm behaves the same and I assume you don't advise everyone to restore from backup the first thing they do. I'm sure there is a simple way to degrade the array and restart the rebuild, I just haven't figured out how yet.

Comment: SU is for the IT enthusiast. The IT pro, would, in a similar situation to you just reach for their (tested) backups.

Comment: @lain Ok. Can you migrate this question over there or possibly unix.stackexchange?

Comment: @winny it's not only an opportunity to backup, it's also an opportunity to rebuild as raid10 (or better yet, btrfs raid10 or maybe even zfs mirrored pairs).  e.g. buy a pair of 6TB drives, set them up as RAID1 (with mdadm, lvm, btrfs or zfs) and backup your data to it.  buy one more 3TB drive, destroy the original raid and recreate as raid10 (3 mirrored pairs).  If you use btrfs or lvm you can add them to the 6TB array, otherwise you'll have 2 arrays.  either way you end up with 15TB with much better performance.  btw, having 2 arrays has its good points - e.g. 1 for normal use, 1 for backups.

Comment: btw, both btrfs and zfs support compression so you may find that your 7TB of files will fit on 6TB.  If not, you can take a risk and use raid-0 for the 6TB drives, backup to that, destroy and rebuild the original array as raid10, and then copy the files back. finally destroy and rebuild as raid1 the array with 6TB drives.

Comment: @cas I will solve the backup somehow, probably a 8 TB Seagate Archive disk. It will take three days to write all data to it but it's one of the cheapest options. Regarding zfs and which raid personality to choose, I investigated it thoroughly before going with MD, and raid-5/6 for my needs. I'm a big fan of compression and I use it on all NTFS machines since it actually speed things up due to the CPU is faster than the hard drive but when I first set this NAS up, btrfs was not stable release. Any ideas on failing sdd1 and rebuilding the array?

Comment: 1. you could try `echo "frozen" >  /sys/block/md127/md/sync_action` followed by `echo "reshape" >  /sys/block/md127/md/sync_action`.  that may get the rebuild running at a decent speed.  2. btrfs is stable these days, even for raid5/6...but IMO neither raid5 or 6 are worth using - too slow, more likely to fail during rebuild, etc.  3. i misread your post - for my convert to raid10 suggestion, you don't need to buy another 3TB drive, you've already done that.

Comment: but i'd find it very hard to trust the array after something like this.  backup, re-create (in whatever configuration suits you), and then restore is the only thing that would give me any confidence in the array.

Comment: forgot to mention - after the `echo reshape`, you'll probably have a degraded raid6 with sdd1 missing. first, `watch cat /proc/mdstat` until there's no resync/reshape activity.  then re-add sdd1 with `mdadm --add /dev/md127 /dev/sdd1`.  that will get the reshape started again.  `watch cat /proc/mdstat` again.   actually, i just noticed `raid6 sdd[0] sdb1[6] sdf[5] sde[3] sda[2] sdc[1]` - only one of those raid members is a partition, the rest are unpartitioned drives.  so sdd rather than sdd1.

Comment: @cas Back from the holidays again. The server was running while I placed an order for a large disk to backup everything to but we had an extended power outtake for a full day for the entire region where I live so everyone without a diesel generator ran out of UPS energy. Since this event, or more precisely, since the reshape was stopped, mdadm reports "mdadm: Failed to restore critical section for reshape, sorry." But I still wounder if I can fail sdd1 and create a new md128 with five disks and -assume-clean and read-only without destroying anything?

Comment: @cas Oh! One can use BOTH --backup-file= AND --invalid-backup. I can mount it now. Just need to wait for that 8 TB drive to arrive.

Comment: @cas Can you please add echo "frozen" echo "reshape" as an answer because that actually did the trick and it's rebuilding to raid-6 now, so I can accept is as an answer! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
echo frozen > /sys/block/md127/md/sync_action
echo reshape > /sys/block/md127/md/sync_action
```

You'll probably have a degraded RAID-6 (with `/dev/sdd` missing) at this point, so:

1. run `watch cat /proc/mdstat` and keep an eye on it until there's no resync or reshape activity.
2. run `mdadm --add /dev/md127 /dev/sdd`
3. run `watch cat /proc/mdstat` again.

That should get the reshape running at a decent speed.

BTW, running `cat /proc/mdstat` via `watch` every 2 seconds shouldn't be a significant CPU load, but you probably don't need 2 second updates for something that's going to run for hours.  updating every 10 or 30 seconds should be adequate, e.g. use `watch -n 30 cat /proc/mdstat` in step 3 above.

Comment: That certainly did solve the apparent problem by restarting the reshape. However, after one night of crunching, it got stuck at 8.4 % again which I interpret as some md-data going bad at that spot.

Comment: did you try running checkarray on it?

Comment: No? checkarray? Is it an mdadm option or separate program?

Comment: `checkarray` is a script that tells the md driver to check the consistency of an array.  I can't remember if it's in mdadm upstream or not (it was written by a debian developer but may have been submitted upstream).  On a debian system, it's `/usr/share/mdadm/checkarray` and is run, by default, from cron on the first sunday of every month.